# changing /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory broke my server

Tags: linux, ssh, memory, centos6, sftp

After changing it to 2 it closed my sftp session, and I cannot connect via ssh or sftp although it kept my session open. Whenever I run a command that isnt cd, I get -bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory. This includes reboot, nano, even ls.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a root bash shell logged in as the question appears to tell, this should work:

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

As it's using a built-in bash command, chances are this should work and be able to allow to overcomit memory again.

You can now hopefully be able to use memory again and fix things. Including checking that the *sshd* (main) daemon is still running or starting it again, and also pondering writing 0 (which is the default) rather than 1 (always) in `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`.